# What is causing E/BufferItemConsumer error messages in Android Studio logcat?

Tags: android, android-logcat

When debugging my android app, the Android Studio logcat window is flooded with dozens and dozens of identical BufferItemConsumer errors on every click. This is regardless of using the emulator or a physical device.

```
08-13 18:15:44.497 6005-6005/org.xx.debug E/BufferItemConsumer: [unnamed-6005-129] Failed to release buffer: Unknown error -1 (1)
08-13 18:15:44.499 6005-6005/org.xx.debug E/BufferItemConsumer: [unnamed-6005-130] Failed to release buffer: Unknown error -1 (1)
08-13 18:15:44.502 6005-6005/org.xx.debug E/BufferItemConsumer: [unnamed-6005-131] Failed to release buffer: Unknown error -1 (1)
```

AS claims the messages are related to the app but no other information is provided in the logs. A google search doesn't turn up anything either.

Any idea where I should start searching to either fix whatever underlying error causes this is or at least suppress the messages? They are more than a nuisance since they crowd out any meaningful log message.

Comment: are you using activity transition?

Comment: @ilya I'm getting this error from a shared element transition between Activities.

Comment: i got this same issue, and i am using activity transition @ilya

Comment: @ilya I'm getting the same issue as OP using an activity transition - any ideas?